# Print date from the result of BCD in DS3231

Tags: arduino

I'm new here and to programming. I'm trying to print a date based on the byte of DS3231. Since it is binary to decimal, my output would be from 1 to 7 for the day of the week and 1 to 12 for the month.

I would like to have an output that corresponds with the decimal numbers to char names.

```cpp
#include "Wire.h"
#define rtcAddress 0x68

#include <BH1750_mega.h>
BH1750_mega LightSensor;

byte date_second,
  date_minute,
  date_hour,
  date_DOW,
  date_dayOfMonth,
  date_month,
  date_year;

byte bin2dec(byte val){  return byte( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );}

void date_get() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(rtcAddress);
  Wire.write(0);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(rtcAddress, 7);
  // A few of these need masks because certain bits are control bits
  date_second     = bin2dec(Wire.read() & 0x7f);
  date_minute     = bin2dec(Wire.read());
  date_hour       = bin2dec(Wire.read() & 0x3f);  // Need to change this if 12 hour am/pm
  date_DOW  = bin2dec(Wire.read());
  date_dayOfMonth = bin2dec(Wire.read());
  date_month      = bin2dec(Wire.read());
  date_year       = bin2dec(Wire.read());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();     
  LightSensor.begin();
  LightSensor.SetAddress(Device_Address_L); //Address 0x23
  LightSensor.SetMode(Continuous_H_resolution_Mode2); 
}

void loop() {
  date_get();
  if (date_DOW = 6) Serial.print("Monday");
  else if (date_DOW = 2) Serial.print("Tuesday");
  else if (date_DOW = 3) Serial.print("Wednesday");
  else if (date_DOW = 4) Serial.print("Thursday");
  else if (date_DOW = 5) Serial.print("Friday");
  else if (date_DOW = 1) Serial.print("Sunday");
  else Serial.print("Saturday");
  Serial.print(", ");
  if (date_month = 1) Serial.print("Jan");
  else if (date_month = 2) Serial.print("Feb");
  else if (date_month = 3) Serial.print("Mar");
  else if (date_month = 4) Serial.print("Apr");
  else if (date_month = 5) Serial.print("May");
  else if (date_month = 6) Serial.print("Jun");
  else if (date_month = 7) Serial.print("Jul");
  else if (date_month = 8) Serial.print("Aug");
  else if (date_month = 9) Serial.print("Sep");
  else if (date_month = 10) Serial.print("Oct");
  else if (date_month = 11) Serial.print("Nov");
  else if (date_month = 12) Serial.print("Dec");
  Serial.print(". ");
  Serial.print(date_dayOfMonth); Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.print(2000 + date_year); Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.print(date_hour); Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.print(date_minute); Serial.print(": ");
  Serial.print(date_second); Serial.print("  --  ");
  uint16_t lux = LightSensor.GetLightIntensity();
  Serial.print("Lux: ");
  Serial.println(lux);
  delay(1000);
}
```

I'm always getting the output of "Monday" and "Jan."

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

In C, assigning a value to a variable is done with single equals:

```
=
```

Comparing one variable to a value is done with double equals:

```
==
```

The code above wants to be doing comparison, but instead is using single equals, which results in an assignment.

The assignment of a non-zero value to a variable is considered truthy.

That's why the code is outputting "Monday" and "Jan".

HTH.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks man! Big help, exhaustion really degrade my understanding.  Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help. Just mark the question answered so other folks can find it in the future. :)